# Update two separated widgets from AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, multithreading, widget

What i want:
When the user add a widget an alarmmanger starts to update the added widget.
The widget takes the data from internet (json resource).
The widget uses a dedicated json page (each widget has a page where take the data: eg. test.json?page=5)

I already have a class that extends AppWidgetProvider.
In this class there is a function: `private void updateAppWidget(Context context,  AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,   int appWidgetId)`
inside this function there is:

```
remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  R.layout.widget);
new HttpRequestTask(SELECTED_PAGE).execute(remoteViews);
```

This is HttpRequestTask class:

```
 class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<RemoteViews, Void, String> {

        private RemoteViews rv;
        private String url;

        public HttpRequestTask(String string) {
            url = string;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(RemoteViews... contextParam) {
            String html = "";
            try {
                rv = contextParam[0];
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request 

= new HttpGet("http://www.hwlogos.com/"+url+".txt");
            HttpResponse response;      
            response = client.execute(request);     

            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            html = str.toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return html;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
         rv.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, html);
     }
}
```

The problem is that the text doesn't update!

Comment: do you have any indication that onPostExecute() is running (e.g., a Log debug statement)?

Comment: I tried this:

remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  R.layout.widget);
Log.i("TEST", "Remoteview sended: " + remoteViews.toString());
new HttpRequestTask(s.getIP()).execute(remoteViews);

and then:

 protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
      rv.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, html);
      Log.i("TEST", "RemoteView recived: " + rv.toString());
     }

result:

10-14 20:36:55.539: I/TEST(26045): Remoteview sended: android.widget.RemoteViews@4104d0b0
10-14 20:36:55.878: I/TEST(26045): RemoteView recived: android.widget.RemoteViews@4104d0b0

Comment: are you sure that the view indicated by R.id.ip is being displayed?

Comment: yes... it has a default text that i can see...

Comment: perhaps you need to force a redraw (e.g., setContentView again)?

Comment: I've never used this... 
I took most of the code from  here: http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 3):

I think you've missed the string in onPostExecute() like:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds, rv);
```

Update occurs when you call appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(...), but when you call just rv.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, html); - it doesn't.

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: +1 For clarifying that views update after appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(...) and not on remoteViews.setTextViewText(...)